# How do I get exact 2 char occurrence from the input word and output that char in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, logic

```
var exactTwo = (word) => 
{
     `crate from word a string of char` 
    var arr = [];
    var arr = word.split("");
    var result = [];
     `it goes through arry and looks for a copy`
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) 
        {   
            if (arr[i] === arr[j]) 
            {
                 `it puts  the output to  result[]`
                result.push(arr[i])
            }
        }
    }
}      
console.log(exactTwo("ABAACCBA"));
console.log(exactTwo("ABC"));
console.log(exactTwo("ABBCCA"));
```

My output of first part of the code repeats itself from the point it gets to one more loop. How do I do this? Olso the hole task goes like this:

In the input string, find the first character that has exactly 2 occurrences.

EXAMPLE:

ABAACCBA -> B

ABC-> ""

ABBCCA-> B

Comment: How answer is "B" for "ABBCCA"? It should be "A"

Comment: `ABAACCBA` gives output `B` and `ABBCCA` gives output `B` - i suspect there is conflict in result. In second case `A` has 2 occurrences and is the first character but still gives output `B`. And if this behavior is correct then why the first one outputs `B`  instead of `C`

Comment: If it weren't for the inconsistent expected output, I'd say the code is as easy as `const exactTwo = word => Object.entries(word.split('').reduce((a,l,i)=>(a[l]=(a[l]||[]).concat(i),a),{})).filter(([l,a])=>a.length===2).sort(([x,[a]],[y,[b]])=>a-b).concat([[]])[0][0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
function extractFirstDuplicatedString(string) {
        var stringRepetition = {};

        for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++ ) {
            var character = string.charAt(i);
            if (stringRepetition[character]) {
               stringRepetition[character]++;
            } else {
               stringRepetition[character] = 1;
            }
        }

       for (var chara in stringRepetition ) {
            if( 2 == stringRepetition[chara] ) {
                return chara;
           }
       }
        return "";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over to each character followed by `Array.filter()` to filter out the same character and then get the length to match with exact two character long:

```js
var exactTwo = (word) => {
  var wordSplit = word.split('');
  var match = '';
  for(var i=0; i<wordSplit.length; i++){
    var length = wordSplit.filter(character => character === wordSplit[i]).length;
    if(length === 2){
      match = wordSplit[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  return match;
}

console.log(exactTwo("ABAACCBA"));
console.log(exactTwo("ABC"));
console.log(exactTwo("ABBCCA"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected answer seems to be conflicting. There are 2 possible output cases

**CASE 1 : Output the first character in the string that has exact 2 occurrences**

```js
var exactTwo = (word) => {
  let chars = [];
  let charMap = {};
  let arr = word.split("");
  arr.forEach(a => {
    if(charMap[a]) charMap[a] += 1
    else { charMap[a] = 1; chars.push(a);}
  });
  let result = chars.find(c => charMap[c] === 2);
  return result ? result : "";
}
console.log(exactTwo("ABAACCBA")); // B
console.log(exactTwo("ABC")); // ""
console.log(exactTwo("ABBCCA")); // A
```

**CASE 2 : Output the character in the string that is first to have exact 2 occurrences**

```js
var exactTwo = (word) => {
  let chars = [];
  let charMap = {};
  let arr = word.split("");
  arr.forEach(a => {
    if(charMap[a]) charMap[a] += 1
    else charMap[a] = 1;
    if(charMap[a] === 2) chars.push(a)
    else if(charMap[a] > 2) chars.splice(chars.indexOf(a),1)
  });
  return chars.length ? chars[0] : "";
}
console.log(exactTwo("ABAACCBA")); // C
console.log(exactTwo("ABC")); // ""
console.log(exactTwo("ABBCCA")); // B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it O(n) time by using `forEach`, `Map`, `some`. like below.

```js
function exactTwo(a) {
  var myMap = new Map();
  var array = a.split("");
  var result="";
  array.forEach(function(x){
      var y = myMap.get(x);
      if(y) {
        myMap.set(x, y+1)
      }
      else {
        myMap.set(x, 1);
      }
  });
  array.some(function(x){
      var y = myMap.get(x);
      if(y === 2) {
        result = x;
        return true;
      }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(exactTwo("ABAACCBA"));
console.log(exactTwo("ABC"));
console.log(exactTwo("ABBCCA"));
```